# Homomorphic encryption in social networks

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, database

I want to gain some experience with homomorphic encryption, specifically possible applications in social networks.

I am thinking about using a HE library (such as Microsoft SEAL) with a graph database to simulate the scenario of a client encrypting their data in a social network.

Do you have any ideas of possible real life scenarios where something like this can be used?

Comment: I dont have anything to add about H.E, but if you're looking for a cool crypto +  social media project maybe you can look into Private information retrieval in some sort of P2P social network to find mutual friends, without revealing your friend list.

Comment: @JaskaranSingh: actually, finding mutual friends wouldn't sound like Private Information Retrieval as much as MPC Computation of Set Intersection

Comment: @poncho Duh! what was i thinking. Thanks for correcting.